# System requirements for Microsoft Stress Tools 

Tags: testing, load, stress

What are the operating system and hardware requirements for Microsoft stress tools?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7f944850-945f-4e60-b6d6-cf7341d7f9c3&displaylang=en#Requirements

Mentions the system requirements. is this what you are looking for.

Comment: The link is no longer valid